# How to display default form when website is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form that should pop up when the website has been loaded. By default the form should be displayed. However, when the user press the close button, it should be closed as the user is not interested. I have the below code

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
    <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
      <h1 class="sticky-form">Admission Form</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">X</button>

      <input type="text" placeholder=" Name" name="username" required><br/>

      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>

      <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required><br/>

      <select class="branches">
        <option value="volvo">Select a branch</option>
        <option value="icse">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar ICSE</option>
        <option value="cbse">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar CBSE</option>
        <option value="mysore">RCIS,Mysuru</option>
        <option value="sarjapur">RCIS,Sarjapur</option>
        <option value="begur">RCIS,Begur</option>
        <option value="mspalya">RCIS,MS Palya</option>
        <option value="chamrajpet">RCIS,Chamrajpet</option>
      </select><br/>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Grade for Applying" name="grade" required><br/>


      <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dob" required><br/>


      <button type="submit" class="btn">Enquire Now</button>
      <!-- <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">X</button> -->
    </form>
  </div>
```

This is the `CSS` code :

```
    .form-popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 9;
    margin: 90px 44px;
  }

  /* Add styles to the form container */
  .form-container {
    max-width: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .form-container input{
      margin: 3px;
  }

  /* When the inputs get focus, do something */
  .form-container input[type=text]:focus, .form-container input[type=password]:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
    outline: none;
  }
```

this is the `js` code

```
    <script>
        function openForm() {
          document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
        }

        function closeForm() {
          document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
        }
</script>
```

In my code above I got a button. When I press the button, the form appears and and when it is closed the form again goes back to the button.

This is how my form should [look](https://www.greenwoodhigh.edu.in/)
Can I get any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is still missing in your code, is the call of openForm() when the website is loaded. Your `form-popup` has the attribute `display:none` by default.

So you need to add following script to your js:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  openForm();
});
```

This will call openForm when your page has fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend the following:**

> Open the form and set cookie for the first time, optionally set expiry time for this cookie.
>   Next time if the user reloads the page, it should not load the form.
>   Additionally you can add a button(not interested) on the form or anywhere on the modal, sets the cookie, not to show the form to this user ever.

**Conclusion:**

> You need to put a proper logic to handle when to show the form. Not just opening the form is suitable.

Please let me know if you need more information on this.